# ListItem.builder diffrent event click

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, listitem

**How can I give different click events for the elements in the list with ListItem.builder?(ontapp, onpress)**

I don't want to create separate listItem builder separately

```
 Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemCount: entries.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Icon(iconsImage[index]),
                        Text('${entries[index]}'),
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }),
      )
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add some example or more information about feature that you need?

Comment: Yes I edited the post

Comment: Are you have an example or something similar for show what result at finish do you need?

Comment: Clicking on an item in the list will do different operations according to the index number?

Comment: Yes, you have a separated Widget in list. If you click on first item, click for first item calls, for second item it be a different click.

Comment: For example, let it be the add event when clicking on the first element, the delete event on the second click. Can you look at the photo I attached to the post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have 2 different lists that are `entries` and `iconsImage`. And you are trying to iterate both of them in one `ListView`. It may work right now. But it is not a good concept of programming. You can define a new model which contains entries, icons, and functions. It will look something like this:

```
class NewModel {
  String entry;
  IconData iconData;
  Function function;

  NewModel({this.entry, this.iconData, this.function});
}
```

And then:

```
  List<NewModel> newModelList = [];

  void generateList() {
    newModelList.add(NewModel(
        entry: 'Privacy',
        iconData: Icons.privacy_tip,
        function: () {
          // GoToPrivacy();
        }));

    newModelList.add(NewModel(
        entry: 'Purchase History',
        iconData: Icons.history,
        function: () {
          // GoToHistory();
        }));

    newModelList.add(NewModel(
        entry: 'Help & Support',
        iconData: Icons.help,
        function: () {
          // GoToHelp();
        }));
  }
```

And then:

```
Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: newModelList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 100,
                  color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.white : Colors.grey,
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: newModelList[index].function, // Here is your function!
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Icon(newModelList[index].iconData),
                        Text('${newModelList[index].entry}'),
                        Icon(Icons.arrow_right)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
```